# How to make a Table View in a dialog custom function

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In QGIS 2.14, I'm trying to show a PostGIS array attribute (text[]) into a QTableView. I'm using a custom dialog made by Qt designer + a python custom external function. I'm about to succes but the TableView is void.

The data_list used for the model is a list of list: [["val1","val2","val3"],["val1","val2","val3"],....]

Could somebody show me what's wrong?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget
from PyQt4.Qt import *
import sys  

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):    
    geom = feature.geometry()

    #search of "myArray" field
    idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('myArray')
    att=feature.attributes()[idx]

    # search of the widget "anArray"
    myArray = dialog.findChild(QTableView,"anArray")

    # Postgres Array parsing
    liste = []
    temp=u""
    for l in att:
        # Delete special char '"' and '\'
        if l == '\"'or l == '\\':
            l = "" 
        # real data
        if l == '(' or l == ')':
            liste.append(temp)
            temp=u""
        else:
            temp += l

    #database init    
    data_list = []

    # jump by two (L[start:stop:step]):
    for saut in liste[1::2]:
        sliste=saut.split(',')
        data_list.append(sliste)

    myArray.setModel(tableModel(data_list))
    myArray.show()

#class used to build a model
class tableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    header_labels = ["num","rattachement","x"," y","x _utm","y_utm","x_rgnc","y_rgnc","ph","borne","obs","date"]

    def __init__(self, datain, parent=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.arraydata = datain

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata[0])

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.header_labels[section]
        return QAbstractTableModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        return self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem:

instead of this init:

```
def __init__(self, datain, parent=None):
    QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.arraydata = datain
```

I should hade written this:

```
def __init__(self, datain, dialog):
    QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.arraydata = datain
```

because the dialogue windows must be bound to the model of the table view...

And now it works!